# element.setAttribute('style', 'attribute :value;') vs. element.attribute = 'value'

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, safari

In javascript is there any difference between using

```
element.style.setAttribute('width', '150px');
```

and

```
element.style.width = '150px';
```

?

I have seen that keywords won't work with the first way (like [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2005/03/setAttribute_does_not_work_in_IE_when_used_with_th.html)), but for non-keyword attributes is there a difference?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both are perfectly valid. Can you give some examples which doesn't work in second way? Are you aware that attribute names needs to be *camelcased* first? E.g. `element.style.marginTop` instead of incorrectly `element.style.margin-top`. The hyphen is namely an invalid identifier in Javascript.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Sorry, I was confused about the keywords not working part, will update to fix.  The thing is that the first way won't work in Safari, so I wanted to make sure the second way was fine for IE and Safari.

Answer (score 16):

The only change I have seen is with canvas. But, then, given an element what is difference between

```
element.width = '100px'
element.style.width = '100px'
element.setAttribute('width','100px')
element.style.setAttribute('width','100px')
```

Since I have not found the answer from an expert, only by experience I will say this.

width is an exposed property of the element, as in an object car.color='red'; `setAttribute('color','red')` is a function which assigns the value to a property as
 in `car = {color:'red',setAttribue:function(prop,val){this[prop]=val;}` 
 Seen as a function prototype would be

```
function element(){
   this.color='blue' // default
   this.setAttribute = function(prop, val){ this[prop]=val;}
}
car = new element()

car.color = 'red';
or
car.setAttribute('color','red');
```

Now, the style is a special case, where lets say, is how things are displayed in a transformed way,
 not its original. A style will not change the property itself and that is the effect
 you see now in canvas, as it was before in images which have too a width height value

How is that? imagine you have a figure of 100x100 pixel original, the figure tag
 would have settings in it for height width 100x100px, (same case with canvas) then
 by style you change the width height to 200x200px the same image will grow to fit the
 new size, will be amplified, but the image itself stills 100x100

Ok, you can test this so you be confortable with the explanation

have an image

```
<image id='f' src='whateveritis' width=100 height=100>
```

See it? is 100x100px

Now add an style

```
 style='width:200px'

<image id='f' style='width:200px' src='whateveritis' width=100 height=100>
```

See it? now it is amplified

Now get its attributes

```
f = document.getElementById('f');

alert(f.width) // you get 200px

alert(f.getAttribute('width')) // you get 100px
```

So remember working with images, canvas an all, do not base size in styles, but in attributes

The default size of a div or whatever is zero

then you may set its size by styles, but the size in fact remain 0x0px

But most of the time programs will work based on attributes values,
 not in styles values.

And, there is another measure, but will be your homework

Then what is the f.scroolWidth, and f.scrollHeight if it is the same as
 width and height (when not scrolling of course).

One final point to take into account
Even when I did the example with car, it is different with elements
since the property color is hidden but accesible to styles
This is, the only real property of an element is the one you write
direct in the html tag code or the one you set with setAttribute
because even if you modify

element.width  is a style not the attribute itself

so the only way to really change its value will be

element.setAttribute('width', x )

I did read this myself and found another question you may have
you may think, I left the html tag with 100x100 and that is why I get
the alert with 100 instead 200

Well, not that is not the case

You can test too for that, do not change the tag as it is

command a f.setAttribute('width','300');

then

```
alert(f.width) // you get 200px

alert(f.getAttribute('width')) // you get 300px
```

in JQuery is the same, the only command to change the attribute is $().attr

$().widht and $().css just change the style

Finally

Is it important?

Yes, it is, because even when for images and canvas work with the Attribute not the
 style, the one which takes visual effect is the style not the attribute
This is, you can set the original size to 200x200 and this will be 200x200
but if you change by style to 300x300 the image will be 300
from then on no matter if you set its attribute to 1000x1000, the image will still
be seen as 300x300
But for example, for a canvas program the image it is working on is a 1000x1000 size.

Answer (score -1):

To set multiple CSS values, the fastest is to use

```
el.setAttribute('style','LIST-OF-STYLES');
```

To use the "recommended" style object, it has to be

```
el.style.ST1 = 'VA1';
el.style.ST2 = 'VA2';
...
```

There is also el.style.setAttribute, but this is even more verbose and should appeal only to Java developers.

Comment: Calling el.style.setAttribute() will throw exception (TypeError: elt.style.setAttribute is not a function), since setAttribute() is a method of HTMLElement, and el.style is an attribute itself, and it has no setAttribute() method.