# Sometimes object.setAttribute(attrib,value) isn't equivalent to object.attrib=value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

It appears that sometimes object.setAttribute(attrib,value) isn't equivalent to object.attrib=value in javascript?

I've got the following code, which works fine:

```
var lastMonthBn = document.createElement('input');
lastMonthBn.value='<';     // This works fine
lastMonthBn.type='button'; // This works fine
```

But the following code doesn't:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.class = 'datepickerdropdown'; // No luck here!
```

So i need to use the following:

```
div.setAttribute('class','datepickerdropdown');
```

My question is, why? From reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875800/element-style-setattribute-vs-element-attribute), I thought that object.setAttribute(blah,value) was the same as object.blah=value??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties and Attributes aren't really the same, however the DOM exposes standard [attributes through properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20001113/html.html#ID-642250288).

The problem you're facing specifically with the `class` attribute is that `class` is a [*future reserved word*](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.5.3).

In some implementations the use of a future reserved word can cause a `SyntaxError` exception.

For that reason, the [HTMLElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20001113/html.html#ID-011100101-h3) DOM interface provides a way to access the `class` attribute, through the `className` property:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'datepickerdropdown';
```

Remember, attributes aren't the same as properties, for example:

Immagine a DOM element that looks like this:

```
<div></div>
```

If you add a custom attribute to it, e.g.:

```
myDiv.setAttribute('attr', 'test');
```

An *attribute* will be added to the element:

```
<div attr="test"></div>
```

Accessing `attr` as a property on the div element, will simply give you `undefined` (since is *not* a property).

```
myDiv.foo; // undefined
```

If you bind a *property* to an element, e.g.:

```
myDiv.prop = "test";
```

The `getAttribute` method will not be able to find it, (since is *not* an attribute):

```
myDiv.getAttribute('test'); // null
```

<sub>**Note:**  IE wrongly messes up attributes and properties. :(</sub>

As I've said before, the DOM exposes standard attributes as properties, but there are some exceptions that you'll have to know:

- The `class` attribute, is accessible through the `className` property (the problem you have).
- The `for` attribute of `LABEL` elements, is accessible through the `htmlFor` property (collides with the `for` statement).

Attributes are case-insensitive, but the language bindings for JavaScript properties are not, so the convention is to use the names is `camelCase` to access attributes through properties, for example the ones formed by two words, e.g. `cellSpacing`, `colSpan`, `rowSpan`, `tabIndex`, `maxLength`, `readOnly` `frameBorder`, `useMap`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense. Is there some sort of reference somewhere of what keywords and capitalisation i'm supposed to use when accessing attributes this way?

Comment: @Chris, there are only a few exceptions where the exposed property name doesn't match the attribute name, e.g. the `for` attribute of `LABEL` elements, which collides with the `for` statement reserved word, is accessible through the `htmlFor` property. For other attributes, e.g. the composed by two words: `cellSpacing`, `colSpan`, `rowSpan`, `tabIndex`, `frameBorder`, etc.. the convention is to use "camelCase", the first letter lowercase, and then the first letter of the following word in uppercase. Remember that attribute names are *case-insensitive*, but the exposed property names aren't.

Comment: +1, but I think the mess that IE makes with attributes and properties and how it's usually therefore better to use properties could do with greater prominence. I think it's a common area of confusion, exacerbated by jQuery's own confusion about it via its ill-defined and misleading `attr()` method.

Comment: @Tim, couldn't agree more... the jQuery's `attr` method just tries to hide the difference between attributes and properties...

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that browsers like Safari will NOT run JavaScript if keywords like "class" or "int" are present.

So it's a cross-browser support sort of thing. "class" is present in JS2.0 [I believe a package system is available there too]

...
I should also note that in IE, setAttribute [for non-class things, since setAttribute should be use-able for other members such as "style"] can be glitchy.