# What's the difference between object.setAttribute() and object.style?

Tags: javascript

They basically do the same thing, why the need for both? Or `setAttribute` is used for things other than style?

```
object.setAttribute("style","background-color:#FFFFFF");
```

is equal to

```
object.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
```

And which is better or more convenient to use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875800/element-style-setattribute-vs-element-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setAttribute
```

Can be used to set *any* attribute of an object, including but not limited to style.

```
style.<style> = value
```

Is used just to set or modify style.

In the example you give they are the same but setAttribute works on all browsers but only newer versions of IE (9+).  object.style is more cross browser compliant.